# Vlookup with radar graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, vlookup

i have a simple radar graph setup, 1 column for headings and 1 column for results. The graph works as normal until…

Id like the ‘results’ column to be auto filled using a simple vlookup formula. Such as vlookup(A1,B:B,2,false)
However, the radar graph see’s all the results as 0. Despite the cells displaying numerical figures (10,30 etc etc) ive tried different cell formats etc but it feels like the graph is reading the formula as text and not the formula value. Hope this makes sense! Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: `B:B` is 1 column, so argument `2` (second column from range) will raise an error. Do you mean `B:C,2` maybe?

Comment: Sorry, yes it is B:C. Typo when writing the question! The formula works fine. Just the graph cant read the results

Comment: Can you provide more info? What range is used (screenshot?), what range did you use for the chart's input?

Comment: Also if the lookup result is text, the lookup would return text as well. Did you try `=--VLOOKUP(..` where `--` will convert a number stored as text to an actual number.

Comment: Hey all! Turns out the data that i copied in all had a ‘space’ put in after the data. I had to go through and remove all the empty space and it fixed it. Thank you all anyway! I apreciate you taking your time out to try and figure this out!